# Ilias with blocked modules

Tags: upgrade, ilias

I have a problem with upgraded Ilias 4.4.5. 
After loading Training with few modules where each new module should be unlocked after completing the previous one, but this is not happening.

First of all, we have upgrade the Ilias from previous version to 4.4.5 where most of the bugs should be patched. Then we look into the database.

But the problem still exists.

Any ideas what more we can do?

Comment: Is this still an open issue, or did the update succeed by now?

Comment: We manage the problem by operations on database and finally we insall new instance of new more fresh stable version of Ilias and we migrate to the new instance. Right now I'm testing Ilias 5 and I'm very happy to use it, because it is stable good piece of software.